# how to list all used methods of a specific .net assembly?

Tags: .net

I have a specific question regarding assembly dependency. I would like to list all used methods in our code base (project or solution) that are from a specifically assembly. That excludes all not invoked/called (unused) methods. In other words, given a (third party) assembly, what methods are used from that assembly?

The purpose is for a initial coarse effort estimation to replace such an assembly.

Having a list of all used external methods is also not that useful unless there is a way to group or filter by assembly.

Not to confuse with the question whether we depend on a specific assembly or not.

Comment: A method to apply solely on .net assemblies maybe preferred since we use F#, unless it works for f# as well of course